# Same query run on both table using trigger

Tags: mysql

Using trigger, when I run update query on query browser for one
table, then I would like this to also update another table that contains the same field.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `abcd`.`library_AFTER_UPDATE`
            AFTER UPDATE ON `library` FOR EACH ROW
            begin
            -- here i want that same query with same value
            -- that i have run on the query browser.
            end
```

What code belongs where I have the comment above?

Answer (score 0):

Use the values from the `UPDATE` query like below

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `abcd`.`library_AFTER_UPDATE`
            AFTER UPDATE ON `library` FOR EACH ROW
            begin
             UPDATE another_table SET same_field = NEW.same_field
             WHERE some_filter_condition;
            end
```

Comment: Exactly you dont understand my problem..My problem is that i have Two Database having same table but the first table is the live DB for my Site and the second DB is just the replica of first DB this is the testing DB but when the DBA update any table on live DB then i want the changes should immediately reflect of my Database table so what the query i write.

Comment: @Anup for that you shouldn't use triggers, but rather look into [Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html). If you insist on going down the triggers path with this, you can try looking into defining your Development tables on the live DB as a [Federated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html) table, and then use the same trigger as shown by Rahul (btw, it's not that he didn't understand your problem - you didn't specify any of that in your question).

Comment: @Anup, is this particular information present in your post. NO ... clear all this when you post a question. You shown a trigger in posted code. Anyways, what you are trying to achieve can't be done using trigger. What you are looking for is `Replication` as already commented by uri2x.

Comment: @uri2x i create trigger but i dont understand what query i write i thought that first truncate the Second DB table and then select data from first DB tabel and then insert into second DB table having same name but its not working.

Comment: Like this `UPDATE another_database.another_table SET same_field = NEW.same_field`?